# Adding SSH keys in the VM are not taken over

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform

I have created a simple Linux VM with GCP and want to store my SSH public key in it. After I have done that and saved it, I click on "Connect to serial console" and check if the VM has imported the key. Unfortunately there is nothing there as I have seen in a tutorial.

Also when I try to connect to the server with my key afterwards, it says that the key was rejected.

Is there anything else I need to do so that the keys are automatically imported into the VM once I have entered them into the VM with Google Cloud Platform?

I have added the key by editing the instance in the web interface and displaying the list of existing SSH keys at the bottom. With "Add line" I can then insert my public key that I created with PuttyGen.
Then save it.

Then I click on "Connect to serial console" at the top of the VM's details page and tty1 opens. It should actually say that the key has been inserted. Unfortunately, it does not.

I try to connect to the VM with Putty. Under "Connection" -> "SSH" -> "Auth" I enter the private key.

Thank you

Comment: Serial console is not a network connection used by ssh daemon. you connect using login/password. I haven't used GCP in a while, but aren't you issued a admin IP ? please be also aware that root login might be forbiden, you have to use a relay login.

Comment: You have misunderstood me. With the serial console I only want to connect to the VM to check if my public key has been added. The connection via serial console is basically successful. Only after connecting can I check and find that the public key added via the web interface has NOT arrived in the VM.